# Integrate yammer embed in sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, yammer

For a customer, I need to integrate Yammer Embed in a SharePoint 2010 page.

I added code in a content editor webpart and everything works well on Chrome or Firefox but on Internet Explorer, it loads indefinitely.

How can I make it work for IE?
I've tested on each IE from IE8 to IE11

Here is my code to integrate Yammer:

```
<a href="http://www.yammer.com/company.be" abp="883">voir les actualités sur Yammer.com</a> <div id="embedded-feed" abp="884" style="height: 1500px; width: 100%"></div>
<script src="https://c64.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_embed.js" type="text/javascript" abp="885"></script>
<script abp="886">
 yam.connect.embedFeed({
            container: '#embedded-feed',
            network: 'company.be'
});
</script>
```

I read on internet that yammer is no more supported for ie8 or ie9 (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2967362?wa=wsignin1.0). In sharepoint 2010 master page, we've got a tag  and microsoft doesn't recommand to remove it.
Maybe it could come from here?

Comment: which version of IE?

Comment: Every version, i tested on IE 8 to IE11. With an emulator ie on chrome doesn't works too

Comment: Can you post your embed code here?

Comment: I edited my post with my bloc code put in my content editor webpart source html

Comment: Try putting type="text/javascript" for the second <script> tag

Comment: it's already put, i reorganize code for a better read

Comment: The script looks fine and it should work on IE. I would check your browser security settings and security level.

Comment: i added in trusted site: https://*yammer.com but nothing change